# Torque2D createTileLayer

Tags: tilemap, scripting, torque

The script reference "manual" is not much of a help. When I look up `createTileLayer(tileCountX/tileCountY/tileSizeX/tileSizeY)` it doesn't say more than it creates a new `TileLayer`.

But, in what unit do I specify `tileSizeX/Y`?
Do I have to clean-up (delete) the created `TileLayer` when my game exits?

*(There was no tag for Torque2D and I'm a little bit short on rep. points to create a new tag)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems a bit stupid now when I have learned more Torque scripting.
For any one else finding them self a bit confused by the "documentation" I can simply explain it this way:

All units (except GUI interface) are in Torque units meaning they are independent of screen resolution.

For clean up, all objects are maintained by the engine and doesn't need to be destroyed before the game ends. In the majority of cases the engine also do the clean up for you if you want to delete an object during the game.